# Дискретное преобразование фурье разница между входным и восстановленным сигналом

Tags: c#, математика, фурье

Собственно есть две функции которые считают Амплитудный и фазовый спектры

```
public List<double> Amplitude(List<double> pty)
    {
        List<double> Amp = new List<double>();
        double aki = 0, bki = 0, arg = 0, ampl =0;
        int N = pty.Count();
        int M = N ;

        for (int i = 0; i <= M; i++)
        {
            aki = 0;
            bki = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
                arg = 2 * Math.PI * i * j / N;
                aki += pty[j] * Math.Cos(arg);
                bki -= pty[j] * Math.Sin(arg);
            }
            ampl = Math.Pow(aki, 2);
            ampl = ampl + Math.Pow(bki, 2);
            ampl = Math.Sqrt(ampl);
            Amp.Add(ampl); //Амплитуда

        }
        return Amp;
    }

    public List<double> Phase(List<double> pty)
    {
        List<double> Phase = new List<double>();
        double aki = 0, bki = 0, arg =0;
        int N = pty.Count();
        int M = N  ;

        for (int i = 0; i <= M; i++)
        {
            aki = 0;//действительная
            bki = 0;//мнимая

            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
                arg = 2 * Math.PI * i * j / N;
                aki += pty[j] * Math.Cos(arg);
                bki -= pty[j] * Math.Sin(arg);
            }

            Phase.Add(Math.Atan2(bki,aki));

        }
        return Phase;
    }
```

по этой формуле написал функцию для обратного преобразования
[image: Формула по которой написал функцию]

```
/// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Rk">амплитудный спектр</param>
    /// <param name="Phik">фазовый спектр</param>
    /// <param name="N"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<double> Vosst(List<double> Rk, List<double> Phik)
    {
        List<double> result = new List<double>();
        double aki = 0, arg = 0, A0 = 0, Am =0;
        int N = Rk.Count();
        int M = N / 2;
        A0 = Rk[0];
        Am = Rk[M];

        for (int n = 0; n < N; n++)
        {
            aki = 0;

            for (int k = 1; k < M; k++)
            {
                arg = (2 * Math.PI * n * k) / N;
                aki += Rk[k] * Math.Cos(arg  + Phik[k]); //сумма всех гармоник кроме основной и максимальной
            }

            aki *= 2; /*удвоенная сумма всех гармоник*/
            aki += A0; /*нулевая гармоника*/
            aki += Am * Math.Cos(Math.PI * n); /* максимальная гармоника*/
            result.Add(aki);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

В итоге, амплитуда полученного восстановленного сигнала больше на несколько порядков, но если привести к амплитуде от 0 до 1, то форма сигнала абсолютно одинакова.
Не могу понять где в коде ошибка.

на вход подаю 
функцию затухающего импульса с параметрами A=10, alpha=2, deltaT = 0.0001, N=200, f = 40

```
/// <summary>
    /// Импульс Берлаге
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="A">Амплитуда</param>
    /// <param name="alpha">Коэффициент затухания</param>
    /// <param name="deltaT">Шаг по времени (в секундах)</param>
    /// <param name="N">Количество точек</param>
    /// <param name="f">Частота</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<double> Berlage(double A, double alpha, double deltaT, int N, int f)
    {
        double beta = alpha * f;
        double omega = 2 * Math.PI * f;
        double t = 0, BT = 0;
        double y = 0;
        List<double> pty = new List<double>();

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            t = deltaT * i;
            BT = -1 * beta * t;
            y = A * Math.Pow(Math.E, BT) * Math.Pow(t, 2) * Math.Sin(omega * t); //сигнал
            pty.Add(y);
        }
        return pty;
    }
```

результат без нормирования: входной - синий, выходной красный
[image: 2]

с нормированием 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Здесь только отладка с заведомо известными правильными результатами может помочь. Ставите точку останова на строку `for (int n = 0; n < N; n++)` и вторую на `result.Add(aki);` и далее по шагам вперед и контролируем значения переменных. Особо обращаем внимание на значения `aki`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Амплитуда после дискретного Фурье-преобразования зависит от числа точек.

Поэтому при использовании прямого, потом обратного преобразования делают нормировку  - делят на количество точек

Вот [произвольно нагугленный код](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2/%D0%91%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%B5) - после обратного преобразования применяется множитель  `rw = 1.0F / N;`

Comment: Спасибо за совет, я так понял что необходимо коэффиценты aki И bki  домножить на 1.0/N

Comment: Да, для сохранения амплитуды - всё верно, домножить на 1/N

Answer (score 0):

собственно решение выглядит так, необходимо полученные коэффициенты  aki И bki домножить на 1/N как выше посоветовал @MBo
итоговый код на примере фазового спектра

```
public List<double> Phase(List<double> pty)
    {
        List<double> Phase = new List<double>();
        double aki = 0, bki = 0, arg =0;
        int N = pty.Count();
        int M = N  ;

        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
        {
            aki = 0;//действительная
            bki = 0;//мнимая

            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
                arg = 2 * Math.PI * i * j / N;
                aki += pty[j] * Math.Cos(arg);
                bki -= pty[j] * Math.Sin(arg);
            }
            aki /= N;
            bki /= N;

            Phase.Add(Math.Atan2(bki,aki));

        }
        return Phase;
    }
```